# How to implement backpressure in an RxJava RabbitMQ Observable?

Tags: rx-java

I'm new to RxJava and trying to implement an Observable of messages from a RabbitMQ queue that supports lossless backpressure.  I've managed to create an Observable from a Spring AMQP MessageListener.  This handles backpressure fine in a synchronous environment (e.g. [callstack blocking](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure#callstack-blocking-as-a-flow-control-alternative-to-backpressure)), but as soon as multiple threads are introduced, backpressure goes out of the window - as you would expect.  The class is below:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.subscriptions.Subscriptions;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@Component
public class CommandExchange {
    private final MessageConverter messageConverter;
    private final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Inject
    public CommandExchange(MessageConverter messageConverter, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.messageConverter = messageConverter;
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    public <T extends Command> Observable<T> observeQueue(String... queueNames) {
        return Observable.create(subscriber -> {

            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            container.setQueueNames(queueNames);
            container.setMessageListener((MessageListener) message -> {
                T command = (T) messageConverter.fromMessage(message);
                if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    System.out.println("Being asked for a message.");
                    subscriber.onNext(command);
                }
            });
            container.start();

            Subscriptions.create(container::shutdown);

        });
    }
}
```

I can't get my head around how to implement lossless backpressue here without blocking or buffering.  It doesn't make sense to use buffering as the Rabbit MQ queue is already a buffer  - so a message should only be consumed from the queue when a subscriber is ready for it.  Is the solution rather to use a pull-based observable (i.e. stop using a listener and instead [grab a message when there is demand from the subscriber](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-amqp-dist/latest_ga/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html#receiveAndConvert--))?  If so, what would be the best practice for handling the case where there are no messages currently on the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep I would stop using a listener and grab messages from the queue on demand. Request accounting and backpressure is all handled for you then if you use

```
Observable.create(new SyncOnSubscribe<T>() {...});
```

In `SyncOnSubscribe` you more or less just specify the action that is taken to get one message (or none if there is none waiting).

Comment: Need some more help on this one? I can add more detail if you need it.

Comment: `public <T extends Command> Observable<T> observeQueue(String queueName) {
        Observable.OnSubscribe<T> stateless = SyncOnSubscribe.createStateless(s -> {
            s.onNext((T) rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(queueName, -1));
        });
        return Observable.create(stateless).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
    }`

This works well, though I'm not sure if the blocking observer running on a new thread is best practice here.